# Not able to INSERT to SQLite database

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am taking a location's latitude and longitude information and add them to SQLite. Looks like I have no problem with creating database but my inserting does not work. Here is my code:

```
private GoogleMap mMap;
    Button button;
    double _lat,_lon;
    Intent intent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        intent = getIntent();
        _lat = intent.getDoubleExtra("yenie",0);
        _lon = intent.getDoubleExtra("yenib",0);
        button = findViewById(R.id.kaydet);
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.openOrCreateDatabase("Konumlar",MODE_PRIVATE,null);
        database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS knm (lat DOUBLE,lon DOUBLE)");
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try{
                    database.execSQL("INSERT INTO knm (lat,lon) VALUES (_lat,_lon)");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"sa",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                }
                catch (Exception e){
                    
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

As I understand by debugging, in onClick() method, insertion fails and it goes to catch. What could be my problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Log` the `Exception` that is being caught, to get a clue about it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of `lat` and `lon` fields in your `CREATE TABLE` query is specified as `DOUBLE`, whereas in your `INSERT` query you are trying to insert `String`(`_lat` & `_lon`) values.

I believe, you are trying to insert the values from the `Bundle`, i.e. values of `_lat` and `_lon`.

Thus, to resolve your error, please rewrite your `INSERT` query as below.

```
database.execSQL("INSERT INTO knm (lat,lon) VALUES (" + _lat + "," + _lon + ")");
```

Comment: Glad that it helped.

Answer (score 2):

You want to insert the values of the variables `_lat` and `_lon` in the table, but instead your sql statement is using their names instead.
This way SQLite treats the names as column names which of course don't exist and this throws an exception.

The recommended way to insert rows is with the method `insert()` and `ContentValues`:

```
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put("lat", _lat);
cv.put("lon", _lon);
int rowid = database.insert("knm", null, cv);
```

You can check the value of `rowid`.
If it is `-1` the insertion failed.
Any other value is the `rowid` of the inserted row.